# "Color Game" - calling random from array C++

Tags: c++, random

hey guys so we are doing our project in c++ class. It is called "Color Game" there is an imaginary die with 6 sides and with diff colors. I don't know how to call randomly a string array. So for example I declared:

```
int color[] = {"Blue", "Red", "Green", "White", "Orange", "Yellow"};
```

I want 1 random name of the color from the array to be the output. I just don't know what code I will use. I'm just an amateur in c++.

Also, we need to display different color name when we have for example:

```
char answer;

cout<<"The first color is: " <<color1;
cout<<"want to play again (y/n)? ";
cin>>answer;

if (answer = 'y')
{
cout<<"The second color is: " <<color2;
}
```

and when we run the program, the 2 colors are randomly picked from the array.

This is just a sample of how will be the output should be. please help me in random calling arrays. thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This is a Q&A site for developers to help each other solve common problems, it does not exist to get strangers on the internet to do your homework for you. 
That said, I think you can probably solve this yourself. Think about what you learned about arrays in class, did you learn how to get an element from an array given it's index? Could you think of a way to generate a random index?

Comment: Why is no one mentioning this `int color[] = {"Blue", "Red", "Green", "White", "Orange", "Yellow"};` In which world does this work?

Comment: Learn the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: hey guys. I'm just an amateur in c++. I know y'all are prof. when it comes to coding. so chill. that is not the final code I will include. that is just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your program and added some changes to make game loop which continues while there are still colors left or user inputs 'y'. I used STL containers, they are very comfortable. `std::vector` used to initialize and hold some static data. All colors will be shuffled and generated in random order. `std::stack` holds shuffled colors and pop it one by one, it works by LIFO(last in first out):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

bool IsWin ( const std::string& color )
{
    //Add here your logic
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // All your colors. You can add new or remove some old
    std::vector<std::string> AllPossibleColors {"Blue", "Red", "Green", "White", "Orange", "Yellow"};
    // Numerations of step, you can add some more there
    std::vector<std::string> ColorsOutputNumerations {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh"};

    //Shuffle colors order randomly
    unsigned long seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::shuffle (AllPossibleColors.begin(), AllPossibleColors.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));

    //Stack will hold our shuffled colors
    std::stack<std::string> RandomColors;
    std::for_each(AllPossibleColors.begin(), AllPossibleColors.end(), [ &RandomColors ]( const std::string& Color  )
        {
            RandomColors.push(Color);
        });

    //Counter just to print current step if there are more steps then given in ColorsOutputNumerations
    size_t CurrentStep = 0;

    //Loop to output all colors
    while ( RandomColors.size() > 0 )
    {
        std::string CurColor = RandomColors.top();
        RandomColors.pop();

        char answer;

        std::cout << "The "<< ( (ColorsOutputNumerations.size() > CurrentStep) ? ColorsOutputNumerations[CurrentStep] : std::to_string(CurrentStep+1) ) <<" color is: " << CurColor << std::endl;

        // You can add win logic in this method IsWin(). Don't know what do you need
        if ( IsWin(CurColor) )
        {
            std::cout << "You have won!" << std::endl;
        }

        if (RandomColors.size() > 0 ) //If there are no more colors then gane ends
        {
            std::cout << "want to play again (y/n)? ";
            std::cin >> answer;
            if ( answer != 'y')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "There are no more colors anymore" << std::endl;
        }

        CurrentStep++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Test play output:

```
The first color is: Red
want to play again (y/n)? y
The second color is: White
want to play again (y/n)? y
The third color is: Blue
want to play again (y/n)? y
The fourth color is: Green
want to play again (y/n)? y
The fifth color is: Orange
want to play again (y/n)? y
The sixth color is: Yellow
There are no more colors anymore
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Good luck!

Comment: gosh. I just copied and pasted your code on Dev C++ and doesn't work  we only use dev C++ in our class.